# Pyhton3 strange loop outcome

Tags: python-3.x

```
def addsongs(code, aantal, liedjes_dir):
    songs = lijst = []
    liedjes = os.listdir(liedjes_dir)
    for l in liedjes:
        if l.startswith(code):
            songs.append(l)

    random.shuffle(songs)
    a = len(songs)
    if a < aantal:
        aantal = a

    print('aantal: ', aantal)
    for x in range(aantal):
        lijst.append(songs[x])

    print('len lijst: ', len(lijst))
    quit()
    return lijst
```

I have a folder containing alot of mp3 files. Files are like 010001.mp3, 081245.mp3 ...
The first 2 digits identify the genre of the mp3 like Pop, Jazz, Classic ...

With this function I want for example 175 mp3's from the genre Piano.

1st 2 digits of Piano are 08.
I go look in my mp 3folder and look for all the files that starts with 08 and when he find 1 he adds the mp3 to the song list.

Then I shuffle the song list and I want 175 Piano mp3's.

the var aantal in this case = 175
from the shuffled list, i want to add the first 175 mp3's and put them in a new list "lijst"

if I use while or for, don't matter. He prints out that aantal = 175 and the lenght of the lijst list = 475.

output:

> aantal:  175 len lijst:  465

Why do I get 465 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lists are mutable references. 
`songs = lijst = []` defines two variables that point to a single mutable list, so modifying one also modifies the other. Define them on two separate rows instead, so they point to two different lists.